# Terminal IDE system install error

Tags: terminal, android-emulator, ide, installation, system

I have lenovo k3 note running Android 6.0 my terminal runs fine but cannot install system v2.0 says something has exception error please help screenshot:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-8VSwC2YDO-d0VCVmtyeVJHN28/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: You say that you can't install system 2.0, does that mean you have system 1.x already installed? If it is than there's an easy solution, if not than you should better try some alternative app like "termux" or "aide". IOException appears on Android emulator(Android 2.3.3 & 5.1.1) when there's not enough space or app cannot write in `$HOME ` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on Android 5.0 and beyond, Google requires binaries to be PIE (position independent).

An XDA-Developers user has made a partially-working Terminal IDE [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1340852&page=7).

If that doesn't work, you may want to consider a downgrade to Kitkat or something.

Comment: On another note, you may want to consider checking if your device is rooted. You may be able to bypass the PIE restriction if you have root.